# Squid configuration to allow all https and block all else to and from localhost

Tags: tomcat, squid

I'm attempting to use squid to mock something on my local windows machine for testing purposes.

I need to allow local applications and browsers to connect to a tomcat server running on localhost, which I have aliased in my hosts file as, say, `testServer`. Everything needs to be able to connect via https, but not http, and all the connections come from and stay on my local machine.

So for instance, I want to allow `https://testServer:8443/keepAlive`, but not `http://testServer:8080/keepAlive`.

I can get squid to allow or block http connections, but can't get it to ever allow https. I've tried lots of things along these lines:

```
#https_port 8443 cert=c:/squid/tomcat_cert.pem defaultsite=testServer
acl sites_server_1 dstdomain testServer
http_access allow sites_server_1
http_access allow SSL_ports
http_access deny !SSL_ports
acl SSL_ports port 443
acl SSL_ports port 8443  #Tomcat ssl
```

I've also looked at using apache with mod proxy to do this, and it doesn't look any more straight forward. But if there's a tool that's better suited to this that would be a great answer as well. This seems like it should be simple, but any help would be appreciated.

Edit: Just realized an issue with ports here, I'm going to need to change the port my applications point to so I don't have the proxy and tomcat trying to listen on the same port on the same machine, so I also need to configure squid to redirect that port.